# I am trying to create my own library/source function on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, computer-science

So far i have this, and the floor and pow have red lines and it says identifier "floor" is undefined, and I get the same message with pow. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
double round_off(double value, double digits)
{
    double roundedval;
    roundedval = floor(value* pow(10, digits) + 0.5) / pow(10, digits);

    return roundedval;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. If this is all the code you are trying to compile, there should be other errors

Comment: My best guess: You didn't `#include <cmath>`

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you can also try `std::floor` and `std::pow` and see if that helps.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, I included cmath but in the .cpp file. this is a header file i am trying to create, to make my own library, mt example is a function I am creating inside of the header.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you use

   ```
    #include <cmath>
   ```
2. Use the `std::` prefix when using the functions from the `std` namespace.

   ```
    roundedval = std::floor(value* std::pow(10, digits) + 0.5) / std::pow(10, digits);
   ```
3. If the IDE still cannot find the functions, ignore the the IDE. As long as your code compiles. builds. and runs successfully, the IDE's issues can be ignored.

#### Suggestion for minor code improvement

You have two calls to `std::pow(10, digits)`. It can be reduced to one.

```
double p = std::pow(10, digits);
roundedval = std::floor(value*p + 0.5)/p;
```

A further improvement would be to not use the variable `roundedval` at all. The function can be:

```
double round_off(double value, double digits)
{
    double p = std::pow(10, digits);
    return std::floor(value*p + 0.5)/p;
}
```

The next improvement would be to use `int` as the type of `digits` instead of `double`.

```
double round_off(double value, int digits)
{
    double p = std::pow(10, digits);
    return std::floor(value*p + 0.5)/p;
}
```

Comment: One more improvement would be simply `return std::floor(value*p + 0.5)/p;`. There's no need for `roundedval`. Of course, it merely a double and shouldn't be a major performance problem, but still. It is *technically* unnecessary.

Comment: @Chipster, indeed.